# Why does injecting an iframe in Chrome cause it to limit it's width?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I'm currently trying to create a Google Chrome Extension that always displays in the bottom right hand corner of the page.

However I can't get the injected iframe to appear anywhere but the top left and it's size is limited on every page and I don't know what is causing it

The Code is -

manifest.json

```
{
"name": "Embed external site",
"version": "1",
"manifest_version": 2,
"content_scripts": [{
    "js": ["contentscript.js"],
    "matches": ["*://*/*"],
    "all_frames": true
}],
"web_accessible_resources": [
    "frame.html"
]
}
```

contentscript.js

```
var extensionOrigin = 'chrome-extension://' + chrome.runtime.id;

if (!location.ancestorOrigins.contains(extensionOrigin)) {
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.src = chrome.runtime.getURL('frame.html');
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
}
```

frame.html

```
<style>
iframe {
background: blue;
width:1000px;
height: 100px;
position: fixed; 
float:right;
}
</style>
<iframe>TEST</iframe>
```

Comment: Try to add `width:1000px !important`. Maybe other CSS overrides yours.

Comment: I tried it with no difference in result.

I also tried adding a css style to the body id with 'width:1000px;!important' with still no luck.

At a guess would I have to use Javascript to override the original pages body width?

Comment: I don't think so, better to use the developer tools to see what's going on.